# group and sum certain columns filtered by name and combine in one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 5),columns=["Col_1","X_1","X_2","X_3","Col_3"])
print(a)
```

[image: The dataframe created above]

I want to sum up columns `X_1`, `X_2`, `X_3` into a new column `Col_2` within the dataframe.
I know that I can do:

```
b = a.filter(like="X")
pd.concat([a.drop(b.columns, axis=1), b.sum(axis=1).rename("Col_2")], axis=1)
```

[image: Result dataframe of the concat]

However, I am looking for a more clean and lean one line version of doing this. Is there possibly something that can be done with `.groupby`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
out = df.assign(Col_2=df.loc[:, "X_1":"X_3"].sum(1)).filter(like="Col")

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
      Col_1     Col_3     Col_2
0 -2.306087 -0.698832 -2.824466
1  0.650526 -0.780234 -0.534918
2  1.844277  0.777565 -0.531298
3 -0.424138  0.423905 -2.853805
4  1.236403  0.848035 -1.332700
```

Comment: you could use filter all the way : ``df.filter(like = 'Col').assign(Col2 = df.filter(like='X').sum(1))``

Comment: @sammywemmy Post it as an answer and I'll upvote it :)

Comment: All good bro ... your answer does the job very well